# Smooth shade custom normals through geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, normal-map, shader-nodes, ambient-occlusion

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEgzuMmJtu8) tutorial to create a Ghibli-style tree in Blender, but instead of creating the base object using particle systems, I wanted to do it all through geometry nodes instead to allow for a very streamlined method to create and randomize numerous trees in the future.

I have been able to get to the step where he transfers the normals without issue. Then, I attempted to use a geo-nodes based method to transfer the normals from a base object so I didn't have to use modifiers. I have been able to get a pretty nice result:

[image]

[image]

This method takes the normals from the base mesh (a sphere about the size of the tree) and inserts them into a named attribute `blend normals`. Then, I can take this attribute vector and use it in the material shader to create the same effect as in the video.

[image]

However, the normals appear very blocky and are not smooth. See here:

[image]

If there was a way I could achieve the same effect that a "shade smooth" action/node does, then that would be great. However, I see no way to do that since the normals are coming from an attribute and are not affected by object-wide geonodes or modifiers that come after the geonodes. How can I smooth these?

Note: I am using ambient occlusion to get the super black values on the tree shader. I have a hunch this has something to do with the solution. Here are the settings: [image]

Comment: There is away to do it in 3.5alpha with the Blur Attribute Node, It blur the normal very well. It may work for you?

Comment: Loathe to download an alpha to reproduce, especially when some unmentioned factors (like rendering settings) may interact.  First thing I'd do to troubleshoot is stick a normalize node between your attribute and your Diffuse (not sure if necessary or if Blender does this automatically).  Second thing I'd do is disable AO.  Third thing I'd do is shade smooth in GN.  Remember, you're not really changing the actual normal, which is used implicitly for lots of stuff, like AO, you're just making something that is being treated *like* the normal by your diffuse (only).